# Issues in SQl querying of data type Date in ASP.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview, datetime-format

This is my SQL select statement:

```
Select * from dbo.RAM
```

This is the output when I run it in SQL Server:

```
ID  Size    Date_Disposed
2   512mb   2013-02-01
```

For populating the gridview, I use the same sql select statement, Here is the code:

```
  adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from dbo.RAM", con)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            tbltemplate.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            tbltemplate.DataBind()
```

And when I run the code, This is the output of the gridview:

```
ID  Size    Date_Disposed
2   512mb   2/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

The issue is the format of the date is different, and there is a time value. How can i prevent this in the gridview?

Comment: did you try to google ?

Comment: yes, and I cannot find the right answer. So I hope I can get some help in stackoverflow with the experts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BoundField.DataFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)  like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="date" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" 
     HeaderText="Date_Disposed" />
```

Which will give you an OUTPUT as:

```
2013-02-01
```

Comment: this will not work for me because my gridview datafield is not fixed.

Comment: Can you post the gridview..? I'm not getting what you are doing.

Comment: ahh sorry, ok I will just explain it here, I have a dropdown list that contains the list of differenct items(RAM). The populating of my gridview is depending on what RAM I will click in the dropdown list. The item RAMs have different columns, for example RAM1 have size and date_disposed only, while RAM2 have date_disposed, date_acquired and size. In you answer, you set the specific boundfield, in my case I am not using any boundfield, I just use a SELECT statement to populate my gridview, I am not using a fixed boundfield because the columns are changing. I hope you understand.

Comment: So you can use `BoundField` for all the columns in the table(RAM) so the change in the column won't affect the result. otherwise what you need to do is format the date from the select query itself..

Comment: yes sir I will just work around with the select query, tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use DataFormatstring  [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date_Disposed" 
                    HeaderText="Disposed Date" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:d}" /> or {0:dd/mm/yyyy} pattern. check for the links for various patterns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date manually via sql,

```
SELECT  ID,
        Size,    
        convert(varchar(15), Date_Disposed, 111) AS DateDisposed
FROM    dbo.RAM
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to tell you, I always use * in selecting, because the columns are changing, for example the columns of table RAM might contain size only. or size, date_disposed, and date_acquired.

Answer (score 0):

Date time formats are there. Please refer link [Date time formats](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/21/sql-server-display-datetime-in-specific-format-sql-in-sixty-seconds-033-video/), [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) for more formats.
Try

```
SELECT ID, Size, CONVERT(nvarchar(20), Date_Disposed, 106) Date_Disposed FROM RAM
```